# What type of conditional is 'If you go to Bay Street, you'd know you've gone too far'?

Tags: conditional-constructions

On this [audio file](http://ilielearning-sd.ir/content/lessons/13/Intermediate3_2/unit_5/listening/listening.mp3) (1:38), the woman says:

> If you go to Bay Street, you'd know you've gone too far.

Did I catch the sentence correctly? If so, what type of conditional is this? Shouldn't it be *you'll know*,  which is conditional type 1?

Comment: As Gary Botnovcan says in his answer, you've misheard the *'d*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things I've learned while reading posts on this site:
- Foreign speakers love to give numbers to conditional states.
- Different languages use different numbering systems.
- None of those numbering systems make sense to native speakers of English.

> So, if you go to Bay St, you know you've gone too far.

My native ear hears no hint of contraction near the second "you".

The semantics, in context, are identical to:

> So, if you get to Bay St, you'll know you've gone too far.

or

> So, if you go to Bay St, you should know you've gone too far.

Getting to Bay Street is a clear sign that one has overshot the target.

Answer (score 1):

This woman is saying you would know, rather than you will know. Since she is unsure if you will go, she uses the for would to denote uncertainty. If she says you'll know, she is assuming you will go and would change the sentence to:

"When you go to Bay Street, you'll know you've gone too far."

Answer (score 0):

To complement what others have said:

The woman on the recording says

> *If you go to Bay Street, you* know *you've gone too far.*

There is no "would".

**However**, there is a kind of short pause after the "you" which is hard to transcribe accurately as this relates to the *rhythm* of the sentence.  As with any language, how someone speaks -- pauses, accents, shifts in tone, etc. -- add nuance to the meaning of the sentence.  You should pay attention to these, and mirror the rhythms as you become comfortable with them.

This kind of pause is a natural way to emphasize the conditional, to make sure the listener understands the instructions.  It's a subtle way to say, "This is important, so pay attention".